# CreateChildControls issue with custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I have a custom control that creates a textbox on CreateChildControls.

I'm trying to set the value of this textbox (trough a property of the control) on the load event of the page that uses the custom control. Unfortunately at this point CreateChildControls haven't been executed yet and the textbox is null.

I called EnsureChildControls on the consumer page before using the custom control properties but no luck, still null.

This happens when is not postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call EnsureChildControls from within the property getter of your custom control to ensure it's built before accessing a nested control. If that doesn't help post some code so we can see what you are doing.

```
Public string Text
{
   get
   {
      EnsureChildControls();
      return textBox1.Text;
   }
   set
   {
      EnsureChildControls();
      textBox1.Text = value;
   }
}
```